# Hadoop 2.2 MapFile creation fail

Tags: hadoop

I use Hadoop 2.2
My code creates a MapFile writer as follow

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();  
Path path = new Path(filename);  
writer = new MapFile.Writer(conf,path,  
    SequenceFile.Writer.keyClass(key.getClass()),
    SequenceFile.Writer.valueClass(value.getClass()),
    SequenceFile.Writer.compression(SequenceFile.CompressionType.NONE));
```

My key class is declared as follow

```
public class ReportingKeyWritable extends BinaryComparable implements
        WritableComparable<BinaryComparable> {
```

The value class is declared as follow

```
public class ReportingValueWritable implements Writable
```

The constructor fails with the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key class or comparator option must be set
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.MapFile$Writer.<init>(MapFile.java:246)
        at DataLoader.main(DataLoader.java:66)
```

Answer (score 1):

it will work fine:

```
writer = new MapFile.Writer(conf,path,  
MapFile.Writer.keyClass(key.getClass()),
MapFile.Writer.valueClass(value.getClass()),
MapFile.Writer.compression(SequenceFile.CompressionType.NONE));
```